# how to handle non english key presses in WPF C#

Tags: c#

I build a program that needs to read (play sound file) all the buttons that the user clicked.
My problem is that I do not understand how to distinguish between pressing the letter A (for example) and pressing on the letter in my language which is also written with a press on letter A (Change language) I have to tell them apart.

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you are using to detect key presses now?  The answer depends on if you are receiving a `KeyCode` or a `KeyChar`.

Comment: if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {
        myFunc();
    }

Comment: i just need to handheld multi language keydown in wpf